# How can one display Gregorian calendar year for an NSDate when calendar in iOS settings is Japanese or Buddhist

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to display the 4 digit Gregorian year of an NSDate while the calendar is set to Japanese.

```
NSLog(@"Date joined: %@", self.dateJoined);
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.calendar = calendar;
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy";
NSLog(@"Year joined: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:self.dateJoined]);
```

Log:

```
Date joined: 2012-05-29 22:13:54 +0000
Year joined: 4000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try "en_US_POSIX" instead of "en_US"?

Comment: @MartinR I just tried it and yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [cal components:(NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:self. dateJoined];

NSLog(@"date = %d",[dateComps year]);

// IGNORE IF USING ARC
[cal release];
```